# Is there a shorter version of wget --no-check-certificate option?

Tags: wget

When I try to use `wget` on an HTTPS site, I need to add:

```
 wget --no-check-certificate https://...
```

This is rather long, so does a shortcut exist?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From what I can see there's no shorter version of the `--no-check-certificate` option.

So you could always make an alias to it. `alias wgetncc='wget --no-check-certificate'` (Change 'wgetncc' to whatever you please.)

Type that into the command line and after that, every time you run `wgetncc` it will be a shortcut to `wget --no-check-certificate`

If you want this to be an alias every time you login, you will have to place this in an alias file or something equivalent. It depends on the shell you are using.

Comment: Your accepted answer is naturally what the OP was looking for, but I'm interested in knowing why one would simply assume he was talking about Wget on Linux and not Windows, and thus recommend `alias`?

Comment: I didn't know for sure. But my guess was formulated from two different factors: 1) Most of the time wget isn't used on Windows. 2) OP's other questions are about GNU/Linux. So that is why I assumed he was talking about GNU/Linux.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that's fine although I wish people would specify their operating environment and other relevant details instead of making people guess and possibly wasting their time.

Comment: @Karan just going to point out that no one ever assumes wget even exists on windows. It is typically used in bourne shell or other unix-y shells. I compiled wget for windows, but I almost always run it within MSYS bash or a cygwin shell.

Comment: INCORRECT: As of 2017 (and earlier?) add check_certificate=off to ~/.wgetrc

Answer (score 45):

Try this: (assumes *nix)

```
echo "check_certificate = off" >> ~/.wgetrc
```

Then ever after, `wget` will act like you specified the `--no-check-certificate` switch. More info at https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Wgetrc-Syntax or https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Wgetrc-Location

Comment: A thing to note: don't add comments in the same line as the directive itself. `check_certificate=off # --no-check-certificate` will result in syntax error as the config won't load properly. Other than that, omitting spaces around the assignment sign is OK.

Comment: This even works with Windows ports of `wget`. 

Answer (score 0):

When I try to use wget on an HTTPS site, I need to add:

wget --no-check-certificate https://...

```
Until not solve, using this also.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1240557)